# Totem Videos unable to play MOV (Failed to search for plugin)

Tags: linux, video, centos, totem

I'm trying to play `file.mov` file with `Sound & Video` -> `Videos` (3.8.2) on my `CentOS 7`:

```
$ file file.mov 
Create Meeting using IS Task room.mov: ISO Media, Apple QuickTime movie
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
$ uname -a
Linux X 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 18:05:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

When I tried to open `file.mov` I got following:

> Videos requires additional plugins to decode this file
>
> The following plugins are required:
>
> - MPEG-4 AAC decoder
> - H.264 decoder
>
> Do you want to search for these now?

After searching it returns me with following:

> Failed to search for plugin
>
> Could not find plugin in any configured software source

`Videos` then installed some packages on my system, but video still did not play, here are packages that were installed:

```
$ sudo tail -3 /var/log/yum.log
Mar 24 16:29:14 Installed: libcrystalhd-3.10.0-4.el7.x86_64
Mar 24 16:29:15 Installed: crystalhd-firmware-3.10.0-4.el7.noarch
Mar 24 16:29:15 Installed: gstreamer-plugin-crystalhd-3.10.0-4.el7.x86_64
$
```

So, I tried it again and now `Videos` opened up my browser with following URL:

404 Not Found
http://www.packagekit.org/pk-package-not-found.html

What else I'm missing in order to play `.mov` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while installing `vlc` package, `yum` installed bunch dependence, which enables me to play `.mov` inside of `Totem Videos` as well)

`vlc` & dependencies that were installed on my system:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ sudo grep 'Jun 08 15:51' /var/log/yum.log
Jun 08 15:51:21 Installed: fribidi-0.19.4-6.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:21 Installed: libkate-0.4.1-4.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:23 Installed: libva-1.2.1-3.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:24 Installed: minizip-1.2.7-13.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:24 Installed: libebml-1.3.0-1.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:25 Installed: libdc1394-2.2.2-3.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:25 Installed: x264-libs-0.142-7.20140728gitaf8e768.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:26 Installed: libmatroska-1.4.1-1.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:26 Installed: libtiger-0.3.4-7.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:27 Installed: dirac-libs-1.0.2-14.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:27 Installed: libupnp-1.6.19-2.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:28 Installed: lzo-minilzo-2.06-6.el7_0.2.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:28 Installed: libvncserver-0.9.9-9.el7_0.1.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:29 Installed: soxr-0.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:29 Installed: libmpeg2-0.5.1-10.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:30 Installed: live555-2013.11.26-1.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:30 Installed: freeglut-2.8.1-3.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:31 Installed: libcaca-0.99-0.17.beta17.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:31 Installed: xvidcore-1.3.2-5.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:32 Installed: libcddb-1.3.2-12.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:32 Installed: twolame-libs-0.3.13-3.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:33 Installed: lirc-libs-0.9.1a-4.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:33 Installed: enca-1.14-1.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:34 Installed: libass-0.12.1-1.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:34 Installed: libdvbpsi-0.2.2-3.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:35 Installed: libmad-0.15.1b-16.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:35 Installed: lame-libs-3.99.5-2.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:36 Installed: zvbi-0.2.33-16.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:37 Installed: kde-filesystem-4-47.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:38 Installed: openal-soft-1.16.0-2.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:38 Installed: 1:libmodplug-0.8.8.5-3.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:39 Installed: schroedinger-1.0.11-4.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:40 Installed: ffmpeg-libs-2.3.4-2.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:40 Installed: game-music-emu-0.6.0-5.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:41 Installed: libchromaprint-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:41 Installed: xcb-util-keysyms-0.3.9-5.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:42 Installed: aalib-libs-1.4.0-0.22.rc5.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:42 Installed: a52dec-0.7.4-18.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:43 Installed: SDL_image-1.2.12-11.el7.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:46 Installed: vlc-core-2.1.5-2.el7.nux.x86_64
Jun 08 15:51:50 Installed: vlc-2.1.5-2.el7.nux.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```